# How do I fix the return type of a Django model manager's method?

Tags: python, django, mypy

I'm using Django 4.1.7 with django-stubs 1.16.0, and mypy 1.1.1.

I have code that looks like this:

```py
class ProductQuerySet(QuerySet):
    ...

class ProductManager(Manager):
    def create_red_product(self, **kwargs) -> "Product":
        return self.model(color=Product.Color.RED, **kwargs)

_product_manager = ProductManager.from_queryset(ProductQuerySet)

class Product(Model):
    ...
    objects = _product_manager()
```

When mypy looks at this, it says:

```
models/product.py:46: error: Incompatible return value type (got "_T", expected "Product")  [return-value]
```

It seems like the type of `self.model` in a model manager method is `_T`, which from what I understand is a generic type bound to the model, which in my case should be "Product".

Why isn't this working? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce one to one your case, but please try to specify what exactly your manager is for by:

```py
class ProductManager(Manager["Product"]):
```